# Excel: Transposing large column with ~45,000 cells to rows with from 1-8 ID-tied

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

First post here so bear with me. It's possible something similar to what I am going to ask has been posted but my technical illiteracy might have prevented me from finding it.

I have a column of data ~45,000 cells.

Within these cells lie descending data of individuals identified by an ID#, followed by anywhere from 1-8 additional cells with criteria relevant to the preceding ID#.

What I'm trying to do it convert this large column to a row for each of the ~5,500 IDs.

[Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSM6ac0QQu_knVbvQfTuZTuAVfMMMMPAQfNEmzHXKETp2-HzyJ6LQKNlexBzm5BQVJEKPyRgP35iJYf/pubhtml)

I come from a beginner level SAS background and have only used Excel previously in a very brief manner, and have been trying to figure this out off and on for a week or two now. I've started transposing them manually but that is going to take forever and I hope there's an easier way.

My best guess would be, from what I've seen so far, that a VBA code could be written, but I don't know where to start with that. I'm also open to any other ideas on how to achieve the result I'm trying to get.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the iDs only digits and with no letters? Are the IDs with specified number of characters that different from other rows of data?

Comment: [Super User](http://superuser.com/) is the appropriate site for general Microsoft Excel questions, including those dealing with built in Excel features, functions, and formulae. Stackoverflow is an appropriate resource for help with automation in Excel using VBA, including User-Defined Functions.

Comment: @kelvin004, the ID's are only digits with no letter. Also, the ID's vary from as many as 8 digits to as small as 4 or 5.

Comment: samoppec, Thomas has an efficient code for you. You may try to change  If Data(x, 1) Like "#######" Then ...     to     If Data(x, 1) Like "####*" Then ... . to suit the ID's that vary from as many as 8 digits to as small as 4 or 5. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your problem the following code should solve it;

```
Sub ColToRow()
    Dim inCol As Range
    Set inCol = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Range", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8) 'Get the input column as a range

    Dim outCol As Range
    Set outCol = inCol.Offset(0, 2) 'Set the output column as a range

    Dim index As Long 'Current row
    Dim cell As Range 'Current cell

    Dim lastRow As Long 'The last row
    Dim currRow As Long 'Current output row
    Dim currCol As Long 'Current output column

    lastRow = inCol.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    currRow = inCol.Row - 1
    currCol = 0

    For index = inCol.Row To lastRow
        Set cell = ActiveSheet.Cells(index, inCol.Column) 'Set the cell range to the current cell

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(cell) And Len(cell.Value) = 7 Then 'If numeric then we assume it is the ID, else we assume it is the
            currRow = currRow + 1 'Advance to next output row
            currCol = 0           'Reset column offset
            cell.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(currRow, outCol.Column + currCol) 'Copy ID
        ElseIf currRow > 0 Then   'Ensure we are within the row bounds and not at 0 or below
            currCol = currCol + 1 'Advance the column
            cell.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(currRow, outCol.Column + currCol) 'Copy Text Values until we get the next numeric value
        End If
    Next index 'Advance the row
End Sub
```

The code simply goes (in order) down the column and does the following; 
- If the cell has a numeric value then we assume it is the ID and create a new row. 
- If the cell has a text value we just add it to the next column in the current row, it'll continue to do this with however many string values until a new ID is reached.

Hope it helps.

-Regards
Mark

Comment: Thanks so much Mark! I did forget to mention previously that there are cells other than those with ID #'s that have digits as well, e.g. year. I feel like that will most likely change what is necessary since your code would recognize the year the same as it would the ID correct?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit it so it recognizes only 7 digit numbers

Comment: You cloud also simply replace the if statement with Thomas' solution; `If cell.Value Like "########" Then`

Answer (score 0):

[image] 
[image]

---

```
Sub TransposeData()
    Dim Data, TData
    Dim x As Long, x1 As Long, y As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Data = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    ReDim TData(1 To UBound(Data, 1), 1 To 8)

    For x = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        'If the Data macthes the ID pattern (7 Digits) then
        'increment the TData Row Counter
        If Data(x, 1) Like "#######" Then
            x1 = x1 + 1
            y = 0
        End If
        'Increment the TData Column Counter
        y = y + 1
        TData(x1, y) = Data(x, 1)
    Next

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        With .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            If .Value = "" Then 'If there is no data, start on row 1
                .Resize(x1, 8).Value = TData 'Resize the range to fit the used elements in TData
            Else ' Start on the next empty row
                .Offset(1).Resize(x1, 8).Value = TData
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I did forget to mention that there are other numerical cells other than in the ID, e.g. there is a category for year as well. Would that make a difference?

Comment: I figured that there might be other Numberic data that's why I used `Like` instead of `IsNumberic`. This tutorial will show you everything that you need to know to refine your ID pattern:  [VBA LIKE OPERATOR – USING WILDCARDS IN CONDITIONAL STATEMENTS](http://analystcave.com/vba-like-operator/)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on ID being 7 digits numbers and all other numbers being not

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim area As Range
    Dim iArea As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Transpose") '<--| reference relevant worksheet (change "Transpose" to your actual sheet name)
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.COUNT, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1))
            .Cells(.Rows.COUNT, 1).Value = 1111111 '<--| add a "dummy" ID to end data
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=1000000", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=9999999" '<--| filter its "JobCol_Master" named range  on textbox ID
            .Cells(.Rows.COUNT, 1).ClearContents '<--| remove "dummy" ID
            With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
                For iArea = 1 To .Areas.COUNT - 1
                    Set area = .Parent.Range(.Areas(iArea), .Areas(iArea + 1).Offset(-1))
                    .Parent.Cells(.Parent.Cells.Rows.COUNT, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, area.Rows.COUNT).Value = Application.Transpose(area.Value)
                Next iArea
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```